# spring boot application always download favicon.ico

Tags: spring-boot, favicon

my spring boot application always download favicon as a file

as follow is my `index.html` link.

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="static/page-favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" sizes="16x16"/>
```

when click any link，it will download a `favicon.ico`

[chrome debug screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHNtu.png)

Comment: just try after removing the resource from static location

Comment: It will download the spring boot favicon (the leaf) after remove the resource. -.-!

Comment: I'm running into the same issue. Did you get around it?